# Adding Values together using FindLabel (VBscript) function of ArcMap Label Expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, vbscript

I would like to add values from multiple fields in a shape file and display the result as a label

This is what I'm doing currently::

```
if ( [SwineGesBo] + [SwineSowLt] > 0) then 
    output = output & [SwineGesBo] + [SwineSowLt] & "Sows"
```

Unfortunately the code here only puts the two value together and does not sum them.

How can I do this?

Comment: In addition to the below comments, I believe your if statement might give you incorrect results.  Try putting the ">0" outside the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Help button on the Label Expression dialog:

> Field values are automatically cast to text strings. Therefore, if you
>   wish to use a numeric value in an arithmetic operation, or when making
>   a comparison, you will need to cast it back to a numeric data type.

In place of

```
[SwineGesBo] + [SwineSowLt]
```

try using

```
cint([SwineGesBo]) + cint([SwineSowLt])
```

Answer (score -1):

Add and calculate a new field with the values summed, then call on this new field in the label expression.

Comment: Ok the concept makes sense to me.  Could you give me an example of what this might look like?  TIA